# Intersections of Invertible Sheaves Invariant onder Pull Back

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a birational morphism between proper integral surfaces, $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{N}$ two invertible sheaves on $X$, and $\mathcal{L}'= f^*\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{N}= f^*\mathcal{N}$ their pull backs.

My question is how to see that for the intersection holds

$$(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{N})= (\mathcal{L}',\mathcal{N}')$$

My ideas:
I want to apply the formula $(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{N}) = deg(\mathcal{L} \vert _{D(\mathcal{N})})$ where $D(\mathcal{N})$ is the corresponding Cartier divisor to $\mathcal{N}$.

But to apply this formula I have to get Cartier divisors $D(\mathcal{L}),D(\mathcal{N})$ which hasn't common irreducible component. How can I force it?

I know futhermore that every invertible sheaf can be expressed as "difference" of tho ample sheaves, so by bilinearity of intersection I can find candidates for the Cartier divisors. But how to make them don't having common irreducible components and pass the equality to the pull back?

Answer (score 3):

The equality follows from the more general projection formula, which states that if $\pi: Y\rightarrow X$ is a surjective morphism between proper varieties, and $D_1,\ldots,D_r$ are Cartier divisors on $X$ with $r\ge \dim(Y)$, then $$\pi^*D_1 \cdot \ldots \pi^* D_r = \deg(\pi) (D_1\cdot \ldots \cdot D_r)$$. The proof of this can be found in Proposition 1.10 in Debarre's book on higher dimensional algebraic geometry.

Using this your claim is immediate, since $\deg(f) = 1$ as $f$ is birational.

Alternatively, there is another way of proving the projection formula in higher generality following intersection theory in Fulton. This is covered in Chapter 2 of Fulton's Intersection Theory.